# Can't open ELF file C:\Users\USER

Tags: arduino, atom-editor, arduino-esp8266, platformio

I am trying to build my Platform.io project on Windows 10 x64, and I get this error output:

```
[10/29/16 23:23:34] Processing esp07 (platform: espressif8266, board: esp07, framework: arduino)

Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
Converting Lights.ino
Collected 26 compatible libraries
Looking for dependencies...
Library Dependency Graph

...

Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\src\Lights.ino.o
Building .pioenvs\esp07\firmware.bin
Calculating size .pioenvs\esp07\firmware.elf
error: can't open ELF file C:\Users\USER
*** [.pioenvs\esp07\firmware.bin] Error -1
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
239736     4912   29568  274216   42f28 .pioenvs\esp07\firmware.elf
 [ERROR] Took 1.31 seconds
```

Has anyone experienced issues with ELF files on Windows?

P.S. running the IDE under Admin privileges didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your user name/folders doesn't have spaces in it?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, it does, and you are right - it could be an issue... but how do I remedy it?

Comment: You'll have to move everything to some other folder without spaces. So many of these compilers and tools still have issues with spaces unfortunately and nobody seems to want to fix them :/

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, sounds like a good idea. let me see if it helps. thank you!

Comment: It's not the compilers and tools themselves but rather how they're invoked and passed filenames by other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly stated by the community members (Sami Kuhmonen and Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams) above, the issue was in the presence of spaces in the Windows user name folder. Thank you!

This is a configuration I used to move the folder (platformio.ini):

```
[platformio]
home_dir = C:\.platformio
```

Hope this also helps someone else :)

Comment: Had the same issue, now its fixed, see https://community.platformio.org/t/cant-open-elf-file-c-users-username-with-spaces/1042

Answer (score 1):

This part looks strange:

> error: can't open ELF file C:\Users\USER

Most likely the path you have the code/tools in has spaces, like your username. Many tools still haven't been written properly to handle spaces in paths so they just split it into two in arguments.

You'll have to move everything under a path that has no spaces in it, which sometimes means making an ugly folder under C:\ or some other place.